# htaccess redirect except IPs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I try to use .htaccess.

Assume my website is example.com,

and I want to redirect every example.com/anypage.php or example.com/anyfolder

to example.com/construction.php

But some IPs don't need to redirect,like
123.0.1.xxx
and
123.0.2.3

Here is my construction.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>example</title>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
<body>
<div>
    <img src="construction.jpg"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.0\.1\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.0\.2\.3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !construction\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !construction\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/construction.php [R=301,L]
```

But it redirect whatever my IP is. Are there any problem in my .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !construction\.(jpg|php)$    
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.0\.1\. 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.0\.2\.3

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/construction.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Try now, i have removed the OR condition

Comment: It works! Thank you! But the IP couldn't be 123.0.1.1 and 123.0.2.3 at the same time. It should be 123.0.1.1 OR 123.0.2.3. I don't know why remove [OR] will work XDD

Comment: OR flag makes multiple conditions optional, in your case mod_rewrite was proccessing the rule on 1 condition only =if Ip 123456  Or Request_filename is foo.jpg. but your rule needs both conditions to redirect the request.

Comment: Thank you again! No wonder you want me to reorder RewriteCond at the first time, but even reorder it still didn't prevent OR flag makes multiple conditions, is that right? Hope I didn't misunderstand it~

Comment: Yes,I think reordering them also doesnt solve the issue if you have a condition without OR and the other  conditions have OR flag set on them in a block Then  Mod_rewrite uses 1 of the conditions to run the rule.

Comment: I truly appreciate your help in resolving the problem.